# local reference optimization in Java

Tags: java, optimization

```
void myMethod(Object arg)
{
    arg.getThing().method1();
    arg.getThing().method2();
}
```

Will a basic Java 6 installation optimize this into a single call to the accessor (probably by storing the reference in a local).  I realize if there are multiple threads the optimizer might have to refrain from doing it.  Is there a list of common optimizations that I can expect from almost any Java 6 JVM?

example:

```
    {
       Object local = arg.getThing();
       local.method1();
       local.method2();
    }
```

Comment: What if method1 modifies the ``thing`` reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't expect any optimisation here by the javac compiler, because the value of `getThing()` can change over time and between calls (for example, a random value, or the `pop()` operation on a stack, or the current time. You get the idea).

Maybe the JIT compiler can optimize this if it sees that the `getThing()` method returns always the same thing, but I wouldn't count on that. Even the most simple `return thing;` statement can return a different value, if the value of `thing` is changed by another thread.

Comment: "Even the most simple return thing; statement can return a different value, if the value of thing is changed by another thread" good thing then, that the JLS specifies that the JIT only has to account for single threaded behavior isn't it?  The JIT will optimize the second call exactly then when it can show that `getThing()` itself has no side effects and method1 can't change whatever getThing returns. In practice that means if both calls are inlined and fulfill the other properties we'll get CSE.

Comment: @Voo: Where does the JLS specify that? If the object containing the `getThing` method is mutable and accessible by another thread this would be hard to prove for the jit.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be optimised by the javac, and won't be optimised the way you suggest by the JVM either.  What can happen is inlining followed by optimisation.

e.g.

```
arg.getThing().method1();
arg.getThing().method2();
```

turns into

```
Thing a = arg.thing;
a.method1();
Thing b = arg.thing;
a.method2();
```

turns into

```
Thing a = arg.thing;
// expands a.method1(); doesn't update arg.thing.
Thing b = arg.thing;
// expands b.method2();
```

turns into

```
Thing a = arg.thing;
// expands a.method1(); doesn't update arg.thing.
// expands a.method2();
```

The duplicate lookup of `thing` is eliminated when enough code is inlined to determine it is safe to do so.  Often this doesn't happen (or make much difference) unless all the methods are trivial.

If `getThing` is an expensive or complex operation, it is highly unlikely to be optimised and you are better off caching the result yourself. (As the JIT is unlikely to determine its safe to cache the value)

Answer (score 1):

I would find it quite surprising if any language with functions that are not side-effects free would be able to optimize multiple calls of a function into one. What if `getThing()` stores something (e.g. how many times it was accessed) ? Would the compiler even be able to tell ?

Comment: The javac compiler is dumb and will not do the optimization. The JIT can inline the calls (if/when it decides doing so is a win), and if getThing() is just a plain getter, the resulting code will be trivial.

Comment: Good point! No, in most cases even the compiler could not tell, except when arg's runtime type is a final class. In most other cases, even if method1() is provable pure in the compile time type, the runtime type could be one where this is not so. Thus, the compiler had also to prove that arg will indeed have the compile time type at runtime. Which is not possible in general, except in some trivial cases.

Comment: @ingo The JIT will inline vcalls under certain circumstances (which aren't that rare - only ~2% of all vcalls in Java are megamorphic) so if the functions are small enough to be inlined and there are no side-effects we'll get CSE.

Comment: @Voo - Sure, the JIT does wonderful things based on statistics and probability. And sometimes it will have to undo something, because doing statistics is not knowing.

Answer (score 0):

What if `method1` modifies the `thing` reference or any change of some sort for the second call?

Although this *optimization* will basically change nothing, to ensure the compiler to safely optimize you should write:

```
void myMethod(Object arg) {
    final Thing thing = arg.getThing();
    thing.method1();
    thing.method2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No optimisation will save you from a `NullPointerException`, your code would be more robust as:

```
Object local = arg.getThing();
if (null != local) {
   local.method1();
   local.method2();
}
```

Comment: Of course defensive practice is good but perhaps not when very widely applied.  Code gets too big and development too slow if I am not allowed to use my "knowledge" of how the program is supposed to behave.

Comment: @broiyan, as far as maintainability (and code robustness) is concerned explicit code that is clear to all coders is preferable to shorter code which contains implicit knowledge, imho.

Comment: I agree on the need to be explicit and brevity is of a secondary importance.  However, what I was getting at was that I cannot imagine defending against every possible programmer error.

Comment: So you think it's a sensible approach to guard against a null value from a function you KNOW should never return null and just continue execution? If the program violates its own invariants just continuing as if nothing happened may do more harm in the long run.

Comment: @Voo, no I don't think so, where did you get that impression? If the code *cannot* return a `null` value it should state so in it's @post conditions; in that case no check should be made. If the code *should never* return `null` it is better to check, log and handle the error condition explicitly than let it throw an `NullPointerException`. My example above shows a condition (as I interpreted the OP's question) in which it is valid to skip using a result which might add optional functionality.

Comment: Well I don't agree that if the code never should return null that I should check each and every time - I'll get an NPE anyhow at the same position - it would only make sense to check more intricate postconditions that may not lead to an exception in the next line. I also somehow doubt that you're doing that yourself all the way through (`if (System.out != null)`? ;)). If I write an application that never, ever may go down then I can log the error at some central positions in the code where I can restart the computation - hopefully without the corrupted state.

Answer (score 0):

Its entirely possible that the jit compiler inlines both calls to `getThing` and then optimizes it by commons subexpression elimination. I would not rely on that behaviour since inlining depends on the size of the `getThing` method. Maybe your method is a simple getter now, but this might change due to some refactoring.

One example that bit me in the past was a getter returning an `Object[]` which was implemented by calling `toArray` on a `Collection`. The getter was called in a loop, suddenly turning linear into quadratic runtime.

Much more important than whether the compiler optimizes this, is to communicate your intent to your colleagues and your future self. If your code does expect to operate on the same `Thing` both times then you should store it in a local variable, allowing you to freely refactor the getter method.